# CMake Deprecation Warning :" message(DEPRECATION “The CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER macro is deprecated

Tags: cmake

We are using CMake 3.12.0. I am using the below CMake script for compilation. While I am compiling the code I got a warning like

```
message(DEPRECATION “The CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER macro is deprecated. " 
“Instead, just set CMAKE_C_COMPILER and allow CMAKE to identify the compiler.”)” .
```

May I know how to fix this issue?

We are using Rh850 based compiler and windows10 machine. Let me know if any other information is required from my side.

CMake Script:

```
# Change Compiler to RH850

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER “${COMPILER_PATH}/ccv850.exe”)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER “${COMPILER_PATH}/cxv850.exe”)

#TODO set dependency files (.d) to the correct location for compiler id check and remove FORCE’s
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER("${COMPILER_PATH}/ccv850.exe" “ARM”)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER("${COMPILER_PATH}/cxv850.exe" “ARM”)
```

May I know how to fix this warning instead of suppress it.

Comment: Have you tried to follow that the message suggest, that is just remove calls of `CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER` macros?

Comment: Hi peter. Thanks for your reply. I removed those macros and add script like below::


CMAKE_C_COMPILER("${COMPILER_PATH}/ccv850.exe" "ARM")
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER("${COMPILER_PATH}/cxv850.exe" "ARM")

But i Got error message in build ::


 Unknown CMake command "CMAKE_C_COMPILER".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/GIT1/prj1/vcu/autosar/VIP_Build/Tool.CMake_v3.12.0/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:94 (include)

Comment: "I removed those macros and add script like below ..." - Just remove the lines. Do NOT add anything.

Comment: how to avoid  CMakeForceCompiler.It will be deprecated
# by a future version of CMake once alternatives have been provided for all
# toolchain file use cases.

Comment: Once again, remove the lines `CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER` and do NOT add anything instead. There is a high chance that your toolchain remains working. If it is not, then update the question post with description of the new problem.